# Do inline-block elements widths get set by their content?

Tags: html, css, width, navbar

Hi i just started trying to teach myself HTML/CSS a few days ago. I really dont like asking for answers id rather figure it out myself. But now i need some help so i can find peace and FINALLY move on. Im trying to make a horizontal menu with one drop down button and links in it.

```css
.container {border:1px solid black; 
            text-align:left;
   border-radius:10px;
   overflow:hidden;}
   
.container a {padding:15px;
              display:inline-block;
     font-size:30px;
     text-decoration:none;
     background-color:grey;
     color:white;}   

.aboutcontainer {display:inline-block;}
     
.about {position:absolute;
        display:none;
        width:100%;}  

.about a {display:block;
          text-align:left;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:15px 5px;}


.aboutcontainer:hover .about {display:block;}

.container a:hover, .aboutcontainer:hover .button {background-color:red;}

.about a:hover {background-color:lightgrey;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href="#">Home</a
><a href="#">Media</a
><a href="#">Store</a
><div class="aboutcontainer">
<a class="button" href="#">About</a>
   <div class="about">
    <a href="#">About2</a>
    <a href="#">About3</a>
   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I cant figure out how to make the dropdown menu automatically the same width as the drop down button. I figured that perhaps the drop down menu (.about) which has a width:100% would stretch as far as the div its contained in (.aboutcontainer) which is displayed as inline-block whose width would be determined by the "About" text-link inside of it. But the drop down menu, when displayed, goes the full length of the screen. So it seems to be the case that actual content inside an inline:block element will not define the width of that element. And although the border of an inline:block element wraps around its content automatically, its just an illusion and its actual width is really the full length of the screen, if no fixed widths have been defined in any of the parent divs (hope im using the right terminology). So is there a way to do this without any fixed widths assigned? If not then thats ok. Ill finally have my answer and know what im trying to do is impossible and stop wasting time on it.

Comment: have you take a look at the other answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an `inline-block` element will size to fit it's content.

Why isn't it working in your situation? You have `.about` positioned `absolute`.

When you position an element absolutely, you are taking it out of the HTML structure, meaning:

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, and they do not collapse with any other margins.
>   <sub>[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sub>

This means the element is pulled out of the structure, and **no longer influences the surrounding elements, or its parent.**

An example of this:

```css
.parent {
  background: blue;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
Below is the parent element, with a blue background.
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Bye bye parent</div>
</div>
```

If you run the snippet above, you don't see the parent or it's blue background at all, because the child element has been positioned out of it, and relative to the viewport.

Now back to your problem. How can we make the absolute positioned element be positioned relative to its parent, instead of the viewport?

The answer is extremely simple: `position:relative;` on the parent:

> This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

Relative positioning means that the `absolute` child elements will be positioned relative to the parent. While `absolute` will still pull the element out of the HTML structure, and it still won't influence the surrounding elements or its parent, the `absolute` element will now be **influenced by its parent**. So, in your case, setting width to 100% will be 100% of `.aboutcontainer`s width, instead of 100% of the viewports width:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.container a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
.container>a:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.aboutcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.about {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.about a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
}
.aboutcontainer:hover .about {
  display: block;
}
.container a:hover,
.aboutcontainer:hover .button {
  background-color: red;
}
.about a:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Home</a
><a href="#">Media</a
><a href="#">Store</a
><div class="aboutcontainer">
<a class="button" href="#">About</a>
  <div class="about">
    <a href="#">About2</a>
    <a href="#">About3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

You'll notice in the snippet above, we had to remove `overflow:hidden` from `.container`. That is because now that the element is positioned absolutely within its parent element, it gets hidden when it overflows from `.container`. You had applied `overflow:hidden` so the end elements wouldn't stick out over the border-radius, so I simply added a border-radius to the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I removed `overflow: hidden` from `.container` and added `position: relative` to `.aboutcontainer`.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.container a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
.aboutcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.about {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.about a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
}
.aboutcontainer:hover .about {
  display: block;
}
.container a:hover,
.aboutcontainer:hover .button {
  background-color: red;
}
.about a:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Home</a
  ><a href="#">Media</a
  ><a href="#">Store</a
  ><div class="aboutcontainer">
    <a class="button" href="#">About</a>
    <div class="about">
      <a href="#">About2</a>
      <a href="#">About3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea i did try that before posting my question. But removing overflow:hidden from .container allows the "Home" links background color to flow outside the containers border-radius. So i left overflow:hidden in. Then when i add position:relative to .aboutcontainer the dropdown menu doesnt display because of overflow:hidden. So i am left chasing my own tail so to speak.